# Moongose .geoNear aggregation, add basic query options

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the `Mongoose` library with `Node.js`, and the `geoNear` aggregation function.

Here is my piece of code, that works like a charm :

```
User.geoNear({ type: "Point", coordinates: [geo.lon, geo.lat] }, {
    spherical: true,
    maxDistance: 50,
  }, function(err, results, stats) {
    if (err) {
      // handle err
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add basic query options, such as excluding documents with the mongodb `$nin` option. For example, I would like to search for users around a given position (as I did in my example) but with a constraint of not matching some given `ids`. 
How could it be possible to add this kind of options to my query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with with aggregation framework. Try:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        '$geoNear': {
            'near': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [ -77.395410 , 38.967995 ]
            },
            'spherical': true, 
            'distanceField': 'dist',
            'maxDistance': 5000         
        }
    },
    {
      $match:{_id:{$nin: [ObjectId("5716163704ca42c7b579c7e3")]}}
    }
]);
```

Query above will search all documents with in 5000 meters radius and exclude a document with given _id.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Would you know if I can add the `select()` method after the aggregate function ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to select only few fields from the request, but I did it with`$project`

Comment: Last question : Is there any way to "measure" the efficiency of my query ? I'd like to get how much time it took to execute, so maybe I can work on getting the things optimized.

Comment: @Saleem, I think if we reverse the aggregate queries then it become fast because qureies on _id will be fast than geoNear so that first we exculde the ids and then apply gerNear on that. Is I am correct in this ?